# Progress 4GL support for SetPoint in Oracle

Tags: oracle, transactions, progress-4gl, openedge

I have been working on issue where i need to reduce record locking time for particular transaction. I read ABL Transaction control mechanism from OpenEdge Doc's and its having simple mechanism as when transaction is complete then ABL will send commit signal to Oracle else it will send RollBack signal to Oracle. I wanted to know is there any provision in ABL to use SetPoint concept of Oracle, so i can rollback transaction to certain point only.

Answer (score 0):

No - Progress either commits the TX or rolls it back completely.

Answer (score 0):

Progress 4Gl is not SQL.  There are lots of ways to control transactions but they do not mirror Oracle/SQL concepts.  The harder you try to make Progress be like SQL the more frustrated you will become.

The big difference is that Progress assumes that you want to commit your work.  There is no explicit COMMIT.  Instead there is exception processing -- if you find that you didn't actually mean to do something then you use UNDO to cancel the transaction or sub-transaction.

You haven't shown any code but I'm guessing that you are probably trying to do something like:

```
label1: do transaction:

  /* some stuff */

  label2: do:

    /* more stuff */

    if something_bad then undo label2, leave.

  end.

end.
```